# Xamarin forms user credentials storage guidance

Tags: api, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin forms application. The app is for company owners in which they can see the employee timesheets.The app can be accessed by userid and password which will authenticate via API.Iam intend to save the user credentials in app and provide a logout facility when they want.

My questions are

**1. How can I securely store user credentials in xamarin forms , in which nobody should get the credentials by decompiling the app.**

**2. How can I securely pass the credentials via API and authenticate (I heard about base auth, OAuth) it with server.**

**3.If someone gets my user credentials and URL to post, but he should not get the 
 data.How can it be implemented?**

Show me some guidance and links. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with `Xamarin.Forms`, it is more about general architecture and security considerations.

1. You should not store user credentials but an authentication token that will be returned from the API in case of a successful user authentication. This token should have a limited lifetime - depends on the business needs.
2. HTTPS
3. Since you will not store sensitive data like user login and password on the phone, the risks of someone obtaining those will be slightly minimised. In any case you could invalidate the token if a malicious behavior will be detected and force the user to change the password.

For storing the authentication token securely on the device you could use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage)

Comment: Thank you for the information bro..Using HTTPS will prevent any hacking attempt on API?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `hacking attempt on API?`. Hacking the API and sending the data securely from a mobile device to the API are different things.

Comment: Bro sorry for asking that blunder question. Can you give me some guidance(links) of authenetication tokens ? I confused between Oauth ,Atuth 0, basic auth etc. Which one should i implement  in my case?

Comment: It all depends on your needs. As for links, if you are planning to use Web.API for example, start from the official documentation and see what are the options.